# Javascript Single Page MVC from scratch

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, single-page-application

I just wondering what is the technique of creating a single page website by using javascript without using framework like ember js / angular js.

For example in php like they can get

```
example.com?view=homepage
```

Can easily get the view and load/display homepage and load homepage's content.

What if in javascript if want to load another page/content?Any technique for building it?

I just building with a simple function like

```
$("#otherpage").hide();
$("#homepage").show();
```

I don't know is it the best way to develop a javascript single website page with this way?Or any technique that you all can suggest, cause I need learn from basic, need use javascript to explore and create a single app page without php.

Thanks lot

Answer (score 0):

If it was that easy, do you *really* think Ember, Spine and Angular would be that widely used?

Snarky comment aside, building a page that refreshes like what you've done, while simple and rather easy to modify, falls very short on quite a few things:

- For sites larger than a couple of pages, your HTML markup will become **MASSIVE**. Not just that, but you'll have to run every single piece of code on every page...per page. Say hi to insane overhead, both on bandwidth and on server-side processing, even with caching.
- If you want to dynamically update part of a page, you'll need to use AJAX anyway. Why would it suck to write stuff using an MVC approach from the get-go, rendering data as you go along with AJAX, rather than brute-feeding the entire DOM?
- What is the problem with Angular, **anyway**? Widely used, bug-free, unit-tested, built by reliable people, and if a bug does go through, you can be sure that the community will fix it quicker than you could

If the last comment didn't dissuade you from building your own to replace an already-existing platform, I would strongly recommend you build your JS to be fed data (JSON or otherwise) from your server and to dynamically update the page. You might not want the full-blown MVC approach, but at least the MV part of it. This will also allow modularity.

Comment: What he said (lol). If you don't want to use a well-known framework, you would still need to build one yourself. You would need build a javascript controller to handle requests for new pages and then when serving the view (HTML markup) run javascript (model) that fills in the data that you have retrieved from elsewhere.

However if you are just serving a static site, AJAX those pages in - MVC really does not apply there...

Comment: @MichaelCoxon: +1. Looks like the OP just wanted to use a custom framework "to use a custom framework".

Comment: @SébastienRenauld , yea, i roughly need a custom framework for a single page web/app,need to know what technique did people use , but What does MVC really apply on like backbone/ember/angular/spine?is it for a really heavy content for single page web/app?

Comment: @Mavichow: it aims towards code re-usability and maintainability. Size of the application is only a variable in that the bigger your codebase is, the more time you'll save by using it.

Comment: @Mavichow: bit late to the party... MVC is all about separation of concerns. You build data objects that provide an interface to data plucked from various sources. Controllers that are the real "brain" of your page. Views that deal strictly with the rendering. That way, you know where everything is, there is little to no repetition, and each unit deals with itself and itself only (+ loose coupling to other units. Keyword: loose).